# How to use function return values as matrix rows?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I was trying to plot function return values, one based on another. My function definition is:

```
function [final_speed, voltage] = find_final_speed(simulink_output)
```

As you can see, it returns two variables. I need a matrix that looks like this:

```
final_speed_1   voltage_1
final_speed_2   voltage_1
final_speed_3   voltage_1
final_speed_4   voltage_1
final_speed_5   voltage_1
```

In the end, voltages should be plotted on X axis, speeds on Y axis.

[image: image description]

I originally tried this:

```
speedpervoltage = [find_final_speed(DATA_1); find_final_speed(DATA_2); ... ];
```

But that would only result in this matrix, all voltage info gone:

```
final_speed_1
final_speed_2
...
```

After all google searches and attempts failed, I did this:

```
[s1 v1] = find_final_speed(DATA_1);
[s2 v2] = find_final_speed(DATA_2);
[s... v...] = find_final_speed(DATA_...);

speedpervoltage = [0 0;s1 v1;s2 v2;s... v....;];
% Just contains the figure call along with graph properties.
plot_speedpervoltage(speedpervoltage);
```

This is really not optimal or practical solution. How can I do this more dynamically? Ideally, I'd like to have function `create_speedpervoltage` which would take array of data matrixes as argument:

```
plot_speedpervoltage(create_speedpervoltage([DATA_1 DATA_2 ...]));
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want but if you want 2 output arguments from function, it is easy. Write a function: `function [a,b]=test()

a=randi(10,[10 1]);
b=randi(10,[10 1]);`, then call it as `[a,b]=test()`. You will get `a` and `b` as `10x1` arrays. Then you can plot them as `plot(a,b);` Is this what you want?

Comment: Is it really hard to notice that I did exactly what you described in the code I posted above? `[s1 v1] = find_final_speed(DATA_1);`

Comment: No, it is not hard to notice that for me. However, I did notice the following. You write the function header correctly as `function [final_speed, voltage] = find_final_speed(simulink_output)`. Then you call it with only output argument: `speedpervoltage = [find_final_speed(DATA_1); find_final_speed(DATA_2); ... ];`. That's the reason why you only get spped and not voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know how many datasets you have, you encapsulate everything in a for loop like this:

```
Data  = [DATA_1, DATA_2,....DATA_N] ;
outMat = [] ; 
for i = 1 : length (Data)
 [s v] = find_final_speed(Data(i));
 outMat  = [outMat ; s,v]
end
```

Comment: Thank you for help! :) I am surprised Matlab lacks native way to handle this though.

Comment: Hey Tomas, you should use my implementation instead. You get faster performance compared to this one

Comment: I was also going to show you the `arrayfun` method which should be even faster if `data` is 1D

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way of doing this in Matlab. This answer is different from User1551892's answer because it doesn't **dynamically reallocate** the variable thus resulting in **faster performance**. The code is as follows.

```
% Declare Return Vectors
final_speed = zeros(20,1);
voltage = zeros(20,1);

% Loop through each data point
for i = 1: length( data )
    [final_speed(i,:),voltage(i,:)] = find_final_speed( data(i) );
end
```

Now this assumes that data is a vector with each element corresponding to final and voltage speeds.

**EDIT:**

Another method to improve the speed even more is using `arrayfun`. Assuming your data is 1D, by feeding in the function as a handle into arrayfun, you can replace the 3 line loop with this line and preallocation with this code, which should give you **even better performance** and **less lines**.

```
[final_speed,voltage] = arrayfun( @find_final_speed, data );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with cellfun.

```
[s, v] = cellfun(@find_final_speed, [{DATA_1}, {DATA_2},... {DATA_N}]);
speedpervoltage = [s(:) v(:)];
```